# Can a child component have multiple parent components?

Tags: reactjs

I was wondering can a child component have multiple parent components and if this should be done? so for example

```
<parent1 /> ------> <theChild />
<parent2 /> ------>
```

both call theChild component separately. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Could you give a specific example?

Comment: React just like html has XML hierarchy so I'm not sure how is it possible..

Comment: Hi Nico, I believe azium has answered my question below. I was thinking about multiple parents calling the class that the component is created from.

Comment: @Xela0000 Do you mean that in one place `<ParentComponentOne><ChildComponent /></ParentComponentOne>` and in another place `<ParentComponentTwo><ChildComponent /></ParentComponentTwo>`?

Answer (score 2):

All children in React can only have one parent. Think of a `div`. Everything inside the `div` are its children or grandchildren, but the things inside that `div` cannot be inside a different `div`, they are inside that one.

However the same function or class that the component is created from can be called / instantiated and rendered by different parents creating different children of the same type, each with their own unique state, variables and functions or methods.

Comment: Hi azium, sorry I should of stated my question better but I believe you have answered my question. I was wondering about having different parents calling the class that the component is created from. Thanks for the help